# Loops in multiplex Data frame python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 47 dataframes and I need to run routine in all of them.
I want to know if I can doing with a loop and not one by one.
This is the routine I have to run to all dataframes.
Thanks

````
x = BASO['X'].values
y = BASO['Y'].values
z = BASO['Z'].values


ecef = pyproj.Proj(proj='geocent', ellps='WGS84', datum='WGS84')
lla = pyproj.Proj(proj='latlong', ellps='WGS84', datum='WGS84')
BASOT = pyproj.transform(ecef, lla, x, y, z, radians=False)
BASODF = pd.DataFrame(BASOT, index=("Lat", "Lon", "h")).append(BASO['Fecha']).transpose()
BASO = BASODF.assign(DifLat = BASODF.iloc[0,0]-BASODF['Lat'], DifLon = BASODF.iloc[0,1]-BASODF['Lon'], Difh = BASODF.iloc[0,2]-BASODF['h'])```.
````

Comment: Please clarify your question. See [tour], [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

You can put all the dataframes into a list and then loop over that list. For instance:

```
dataframes = [BASO1, BASO2, BASO3]

for index, BASO in enumerate(dataframes):
    x = BASO['X'].values
    y = BASO['Y'].values
    z = BASO['Z'].values


    ecef = pyproj.Proj(proj='geocent', ellps='WGS84', datum='WGS84')
    lla = pyproj.Proj(proj='latlong', ellps='WGS84', datum='WGS84')
    BASOT = pyproj.transform(ecef, lla, x, y, z, radians=False)
    BASODF = pd.DataFrame(BASOT, index=("Lat", "Lon", "h")).append(BASO['Fecha']).transpose()
    dataframes[index] = BASODF.assign(DifLat = BASODF.iloc[0,0]-BASODF['Lat'], DifLon = BASODF.iloc[0,1]-BASODF['Lon'], Difh = BASODF.iloc[0,2]-BASODF['h'])
```

Here list dataframes should contain all your dataframe instances. Then it loops over each dataframe where `enumerate(dataframes)` gets dataframe and its index in list which is then used on last line to write changes directly into the looped list.

If you want to have separate names again after processing those dataframes you can do:

```
BASO1, BASO2, BASO3 = dataframes
```

I hope this helps.